# Value error and unable to sort each line of arrays from an input file

Tags: python

I am writing a function to check if an array of integers is sorted in an increasing order, return True if it is. I have to test it with at least with 4 arrays from an input file. An input file include:
11, 22, 33, 10, 1999, 89 (line 1)
22, 77, 88 (line 2)
22, 33, 44, 66 (line 3)
33, 44, 55, 66 (line 4).
Below is my code:

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
file = open(file_name, 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    curr_arr = []
    for i in line.split(','):
        curr_arr += [int(i)]

def is_sorted(curr_arr):
    if(len(curr_arr) < 1):
        return True
    if (len(curr_arr) > 2):
        curr_min = curr_arr[0]
        for curr_element in curr_arr:
            if curr_element >= curr_min:
                curr_min == curr_element
            else:
                return False

        return True

print '\nArrays of integers in {} are sorted in an increasing fashion: {}'.format(curr_arr, is_sorted(curr_arr))
```

When I tried to run the code, I got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' at line 9 and my code only return 1 array when I tried to test it with a file of 4 arrays.

This is my output:

Arrays of integers in [9, 10, 11, 12] are sorted in an increasing fashion: True

Comment: You're attempting to call `int` on a space character, or some other kind of whitespace character. Double check what `split` is returning, as I suspect it's not what you think.

Comment: Why don't you use just sort and compare the original list and sorted list ?

Comment: @Sandeep Lade: i'm asked to loop thru arr by element and not allow to use sort to compare..

Comment: You should give us the contents of the file from which your program reads the arrays.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: i'm trying to convert each element at the split array into ints. Sorry, Im new to python, so could you explain again? Thanks

Comment: @user8786892 You're getting the error because `i` is a space character; a ' '. `int(' ')` doesn't make sense. Again, look at what `split` is returning.

Comment: @user8786892 But exactly how are they laid out? Where are the commas, newlines, etc.?

Comment: Your code doesn't raise a `ValueError` for me. The reason you are only processing the last array of values is because the `for` loop at the beginning reinitializes `curr_arr = []` for every line it processes, so only values from the last line end up in it when the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `i` takes on the value of the empty string `''` (as stated in the very end of your error message if you look carefully). Thus, `line.split(',')` has returned a list which include `''`, which happens if `line` itself is the empty string (but that should not be a possible outcome of `readlines()`), or if one of your lines start or end with a `,`. You should try to print out the result of `line.split(',')`, as in

```
for line in file.readlines():
    curr_arr = []
    numbers = line.split(',')
    print(numbers)  # Look for unexpected output
    for i in numbers:
        curr_arr += [int(i)]
```

On another note, your `is_sorted` function does not return anything (that is, it defaults to return `None`) if the length of the array is 2, because this case is not catched by your conditions. To fix this, replace `if (len(curr_arr) > 2):` with `if (len(curr_arr) >= 2):`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Between, it returns false for 1 array only when I use 'print is_sorted', and even the array is in an increasing order. and when i tested 'print (numbers)', it gave me '\n' at the end of each array. I just added the content of file in my question. Would be appreciate if I can get feedback from you. Thank you.

Comment: The newline `\n` should not be a problem, as long as the string containing it also contain some number. *Exactly* what does `print(numbers)` print right before the error occurs?

Comment: i got it work now after I indent print for is_sort(curr_arr). Just the if statement doesn't give me the correct True/ False answer

Answer (score 0):

As I said I couldn't reproduce the `ValueError` problem. This is the input file I used for testing:

```
11, 22, 33, 10, 1999, 89
22, 33, 44, 99, 66, 77, 88, 50
22, 77, 88
22, 33, 44, 66
33, 44, 55, 66
```

The reason only the last row being processed is because the `for` loop at the beginning of your code keeps reinitializing the `curr_arr` list for every line processed, so only values from the last line processed end up being in it.

Here's a modified version of your code that still does that, but only after appending the values from the current line to a new list-of-lists variable called `arrays` I added—which is what I think you want (or is very close to it):

```
import sys

def is_sorted(curr_arr):
    if len(curr_arr) < 1:
        return True
    elif len(curr_arr) >= 2:
        curr_min = curr_arr[0]
        for curr_element in curr_arr[1:]:
            if curr_element < curr_min:
                return False
            else:
                curr_min = curr_element

    return True

#file_name = sys.argv[1]
file_name = 'arrays.txt'

arrays = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        curr_arr = []
        for i in line.split(','):
            curr_arr.append(int(i))
        arrays.append(curr_arr)

for curr_arr in arrays:
    print 'Array of integers in {} are sorted in an increasing fashion: {}'.format(
        curr_arr, is_sorted(curr_arr))
```

Output:

```
Array of integers in [11, 22, 33, 10, 1999, 89] are sorted in an increasing fashion: False
Array of integers in [22, 33, 44, 99, 66, 77, 88, 50] are sorted in an increasing fashion: False
Array of integers in [22, 77, 88] are sorted in an increasing fashion: True
Array of integers in [22, 33, 44, 66] are sorted in an increasing fashion: True
Array of integers in [33, 44, 55, 66] are sorted in an increasing fashion: True
```

Comment: Thanks @martineau, I tested with an array of [22, 33, 44, 99, 66, 77, 88, 50], it gives me True answer. Not sure why..

Comment: user8786892: Oops, I introduced a bug in `is_sorted()` when I was trying to optimize it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `.strip()` your input lines before `split()`ing. Here's some ways to read the data and check if sorted using list comprehensions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io

file_ = io.StringIO("""11, 22, 33, 10, 1999, 89
22, 77, 88
22, 33, 44, 66
33, 44, 55, 66""")


def is_sorted(array):
    return all(a <= b
               for a, b in zip(array, array[1:]))


arrays = (tuple(int(n)
                for n in line.strip().split(','))
          for line in file_)
for curr_arr in arrays:
    print('\nArrays of integers in {} are sorted in an increasing fashion: {}'
          .format(curr_arr, is_sorted(curr_arr))
    )
```